# What is the significance of hand imprint of the departed soul in ash of cow dung set in a plate in a locked room overnight, after Garud Puran?

Tags: rituals, death

We were told to perform this i.e., placing ash of cow dung in a plate in a locked room, for the probable hope that the hand imprint of our loved one would appear. What is the significance of this? What if the hand imprint doesn't appear? What does that mean?

Comment: Can you explain some background to the question? Is this some ritual done after some departs? I modified the question o make it general and less advice seeking. What is this ritual for?

Comment: Why u have put "after Garud Puran" in Q title?...You can find details in [this](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:85f22493-a5cf-4611-aa49-a7cf179993ad/download_file?file_format=application/pdf&safe_filename=602323829.pdf&type_of_work=Thesis) pdf on text page 64 and pdf page 68...